# Regex replace all commas with value

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that looks like this: "Doe, John, A" (lastname, firstname, middle initial).

I'm trying to write a regular expression that converts the string into "Doe*John*A".

However, I have to take into account all spaces for this string so "Doe    , John    , A" would still convert into "Doe*John*A".

ALSO, the string "Doe John A" should convert into "Doe*John*A".

I started writing this, but I think I'm stuck on the spaces & the possibility of the user not supplying the commas.

Here's what I have:

```
var myString = "John, Doe, A";
var myOtherString = "John  Doe   A";


var myFunction = function (aString) {
        aString = aString.replace(", ", "*");
        aString = aString.replace(", ", "*");

return aString;

};
```

These should both return `"Doe*John*A"`.

I think I'm repeating myself too much in this function. I'm also not taking into account the possibility that no commas will be provided.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, there is. Use the `replace` function with a regex instead. That has a few advantages. Firstly, you don't have to call it twice anymore. Secondly it's really easy to account for an arbitrary amount of spaces and an optional comma:

```
aString = aString.replace(/[ ]*,[ ]*|[ ]+/g, '*');
```

Note that the square brackets around the spaces are optional, but I find they make the space characters more easily readable. If you want to allow/remove any kind of whitespace there (tabs and line breaks, too), use `\s` instead:

```
aString = aString.replace(/\s*,\s*|\s+,/g, '*');
```

Note that in both cases we cannot simply make the comma optional, because that would allow zero-width matches, which would introduce a `*` at every single position in the string. (Thanks to CruorVult for pointing this out)

Comment: `"Doe , John , A".replace(/\s*,?\s*/g, '*');//"*D*o*e**J*o*h*n**A*"`

Comment: What if I wanted to replace the *s with dashes? Would I just change this to be
 `aString = aString.replace(/[ ]*,[ ]*|[ ]+/g, '-'); ?`

--thanks for the helpful answer, btw.

Comment: @1__ yup, the second parameter is the replacement string

Comment: @CruorVult will you please solve my question? i know you have solved such type of issue. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27010351/unbalanced-calls-to-begin-end-appearance-transitions-for-qlremotepreviewcontent)

Answer (score 8):

If you want to replace all non-word characters try this:

```
str.replace(/\W+/g, '*');
```

Answer (score 3):

String.replace only replaces the first occurence. To replace them all, add the "g" flag for "global". You can also use character groups and the +operator (one or more) to match chains of characters:

```
aString.replace("[,\s]+", "*", "g");
```

This will replace all chains of commas and whitespaces with a `*`.

Comment: again, this is not how regexes are written and how modifiers are applied in javascript

Answer (score 1):

Try this out to remove all spaces and commas, then replace with *.

`Myname= myname.replace(/[,\s]/,"*")`

Editted as removing 'at least two items' from the pattern. But to have at least on item.

`Myname= myname.replace(/([,\s]{1,})/,"*")`

[Reference: on Rublar](http://rubular.com/r/6btBOKRqHy). However you are better off with regexpal as per m.buettner :)

Comment: You should have made it "at least one item". Now you will get as many `*` as you had spaces and commas before

Comment: Yup, that's right, but that's not the pattern in your answer (you should use [regexpal](http://regexpal.com) though, since it's a Javascript question)

Comment: @m.buettner thank you for regexpal. I usually depend on multiple chopping in rublar then adjust it for c#,javascript etc.. Now this makes things convenient.

Comment: there is also [RegexHero](http://regexhero.net/) for .NET and [RegexPlanet](http://www.regexplanet.com/) for a few other ones (it's mostly, the go-to tester for Java, though, I think)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21420/discussion-between-boncodigo-and-m-buettner)