# What is the regular expression to replace white space with a specified character?

Tags: c#, regex

I have searched lot of questions and answers but, I just got lengthy and complicated expressions. Now I want to replace all white spaces from the string. I know it can be done by regex. but, I don't have enough knowledge about regex and how to replace all white space with ','(comma) using it. I have checked some links but, I didn't get exact answer. If you have any link of posted  question or answer like this. please suggest me.

My string is defined as below.

```
string sText = "BankMaster      AccountNo              decimal      To   varchar";
```

and the result should be return as below.

```
"BankMaster,AccountNo,decimal,To,varchar"
```

**Full Code:**

```
string sItems = Clipboard.GetText();
string[] lines = sItems.Split('\n');
for (int iLine =0; iLine<lines.Length;iLine++)
{
    string sLine = lines[iLine];
    sLine = //CODE TO REPLACE WHITE SPACE WITH ','
    string[] cells = sLine.Split(',');

    grdGrid.Rows.Add(iLine, cells[0], cells[1], cells[2], cells[4]);
}
```

**Additional Details**

I have more than 16000 line in a list. and all lines are same formatted like given example above. So, I am going to use regular expression instead of loop and recursive function call. If you have any other way to make this process more faster than regex then please suggest me.

Comment: Can I ask why do you want to do this using regex? It's far more efficient to use a single loop.

Comment: Regex.Replace(sText, @"\s", ","); < this?

Comment: @korhner I have more than 16000 lines in the list and i have to convert all that lines also.

Comment: @korhner I don't know which method is faster. if you have any suggestion to do this in minimum time then it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
string result = Regex.Replace(sText, "\\s+", ",");
```

`\s+` stands for "capture all sequential whitespaces of any kind".

By whitespace regex engine undeerstands space (), tab (`\t`), newline (`\n`) and caret return (`\r`)

Answer (score 1):

```
string a = "Some    text  with   spaces";
Regex rgx = new Regex("\\s+");
string result = rgx.Replace(a, ",");

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

The code above will replace all the white spaces with ',' character

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sText = Regex.Replace(sText , @"\s+", ",");
```

Comment: Now it doesn't compile

Comment: I forgot the @! hehehe

Comment: And here's the question to you: did you rush to post first answer so much so you didn't even check it?

Comment: I checked my first answer! " ", ",", then changed by \s and I forgot the scape \ hehe, then you corrected me ;) Thanks! ANd yes, you are right!

Comment: @OscarBralo And what would be the output?

Comment: @Nimesh you are right Nimesh! Now, finally fixed.. Thanks for help fixing!

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
string str = "BankMaster      AccountNo              decimal      To   varchar";
StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();
str=str.Trim(); //trim before logic to avoid any trailing/leading whitespaces.
foreach(char ch in str)
{
          if (ch == ' ' && temp[temp.Length-1] != ',')
            {
                temp.Append(",");
            }
            else if (ch != ' ')
            {
                temp.Append(ch.ToString());
            }
}
  Console.WriteLine(temp);
```

**Output:**

```
BankMaster,AccountNo,decimal,To,varchar
```

Answer (score 0):

there are lot's of samples to do that by regular expressions:

- [Flex: replace all spaces with comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504863/flex-replace-all-spaces-with-comma),

  [Regex replace all commas with value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13955904/regex-replace-all-commas-with-value),

  http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=896548,

  http://www.dslreports.com/forum/r20971008-sed-help-whitespace-to-comma